# How to plot multiple lines with several conditions (6*2*3) in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am trying to plot this data frame which has total of rows 36 *  columns 7:
Notes:

There are 6 factors for stim_ending_t= 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5

Three are three repeated conditons:

```
visbility =1 soundvolume=0 (visbility)
visbility =0 soundvolume=1 (soundvolume)
visbility = 0 soundvolume=0 (this sould be called blank or empty)
```

date frame name: master_all_r.csv

```
stim_ending_t visbility soundvolume Opening_text               m     sd coefVar
          <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1             1         0           0 Now focus on the Image  1.70  1.14    0.670
2             1         0           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.57  0.794   0.504
3             1         0           1 Now focus on the Image  1.62  1.25    0.772
4             1         0           1 Now focus on the Sound  1.84  1.17    0.637
5             1         1           0 Now focus on the Image  3.19 17.2     5.38 
6             1         1           0 Now focus on the Sound  1.59  0.706   0.444
```

**How the plot should look like:**
x= Stim_ending_t , y=m

I need three lines in the same plot that satisfy the conditions above while being divided into two groups by = Opening_text. If it possible it can be in one graph, but if not the two groups (Now focus on the Image & Now focus on the Sound) can be split into two separate graphs.

I have tried this code:

```
ggplot(test_master, aes(x=stim_ending_t, y=m, group=Opening_text, visbility, soundvolume)) +
geom_line(aes(linetype=Opening_text, visbility, soundvolume))+
geom_point()
```

But got this `Warning message:
Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation:` 
this is the result I got [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b5e2.png)

Ideally, the plot should look like this, but with three lines
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkNfk.png). I found these plots  [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

If you would like to download the excel file, you can find it [here](https://github.com/MohJumper/VisualAuditoryModality) under the name **master_all_r.csv**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

[image]

```
library(tidyvere)
library(readr)

test_master <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohJumper/VisualAuditoryModality/master/master_all_r.csv")

test_master %>%
  mutate(visbility_sound = case_when(
           visbility == 1 & soundvolume == 0 ~ "visibility",
           visbility == 0 & soundvolume == 1 ~ "soundvolume",
           visbility == 0 & soundvolume == 0 ~ "empty")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(visbility_sound), factor) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = stim_ending_t, y = m, color = visbility_sound)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = visbility_sound)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Opening_text) +
  theme_minimal()
```

So here's what's happenning:

- use some simple conditional logic to parse your columns out into a single column
- convert the new column into a factor column
- pop into ggplot with the color set by the new marker column
- tell `geom_line` to also use this column for linetype
- separate into two plots with `facet_wrap` (could also use `facet_grid`!)
- set the theme to something easier on the eyes ;)

Comment: I am greatly thankful for your immediate help @Zafar. One thing though I got this warning message: "There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)." I am not sure how to view the warnings?

Comment: you can use `warnings()`. Remeber to upvote and mark as best answer if this helped ;)

Comment: Already done, thanks again. 
I did warnings(my data frame): this is what I got ```1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots, caller_env()) :
  Unequal factor levels: coercing to character Error in cat("1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots, caller_env()) :\n  Unequal factor levels: coercing to character",  : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat' ```

Comment: oh, that just means that you had some factors coming in. Converting to character upfront can rectify this :)